# JavaFX, Windows, как закруглить края слоя?

Tags: java, css, javafx

[image]
Добрый день, я пытаюсь закруглить края слоя, однако появляется белый фон. Поскажите, пожалуйста, как это исправить. Закрыглить пыталась с помощью css: -fx-border-radius и -fx-background-radius

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Нашла ответ на английской версии сайта:)

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст ответа можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста ответа

Comment: К вышесказанному: при добавлении информации с другого ресурса нужно давать ссылку на источник (на сам ответ в данном случае).

Answer (score 1):

Создайте `Rectangle` необходимого размера, задайте ему такое же закругление края при помощи `setArcHeight()` и `.setArcWidth()` как у вашего слоя и установите для слоя ограничения отображения при помощи `.setClip()`. Все что будет оказываться за пределами `Rectangle` визуально отображаться не будет.

Замечу что значения `ArcHeight` и `ArcWidth` могут быть не похожи на значения `-fx-border-radius` и `-fx-background-radius` для достижения необходимого результата. Возможно придется подобрать другие.

Небольшой пример:

```
   Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(300,120);
   rect.setArcHeight(40.0);
   rect.setArcWidth(40.0);
   yourLayout.setClip(rect);
```

UPD: То что я описал выше действительно нужно применять для внутренних элементов сцены. Для Scene же есть: `scene.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT)`

и для Stage:`stage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT)`

Которые скорее всего нужно будет применить оба.